Why does this code only require 1 delay element to implement?
This is from Coursera DSP class, course 2, week 2 homework.

The following bit of Python code implements a discrete-time filter
(assume x[n] and y[n] are suitably defined arrays):
f = 0;
g = 0;
for n in range(0, L-1):
    y[n] = x[n] + f;
    g = -f;
    f = -x[n] + 0.5 * y[n] + g;

EDIT: adding the question itself as below:
What is the minimum number of delays necessary to implement this
filter efficiently?

My answer was 2, and it was wrong. Later I re-draw the filter structure and it seems the right answer is 1.
Is my following filter structure correct?
I draw it from originally 3 delay, to 2, then 1 delay:

EDIT:
Also, I found sometimes it is hard to simplify a filter struture.
I know by Z transform linearity, we can switch the intermediate node for example:
say if we can separate a filter into H1(z) then H2(z),
x[n] -> H1(z) -> H2(z) -> y[n]

then we can switch H1 and H2
x[n] -> H2(z) -> H1(z) -> y[n]

But in above homework (the python code one), I am not able to do the same.
Is there a better way to do so? Or maybe I missed something?

If your diagrams are correct, you have come most of the way to answering your own question

That's an odd chunk of code, for sure.
I would start with the difference equations first and then draw the block diagram. Delays can be explicit or implicit. Explicit delays are implemented as offsets to the index, i.e. $x[n-1]$ or $y[n-M]$. You don't have any of these here. Implicit delays happen in the inner loop when variables are updated only AFTER they are used in the inner loop.  This means that that variable still has the value from the previous loop iteration so it's a one sample delay.
Let's write this out
$$ y[n] = x[n] + f[n-1] \tag{1} $$
$$ g = -f[n-1] \tag{2} $$ $$
 f[n] = -x[n] + 0.5y[n] + g = -x[n] + 0.5y[n] - f[n-1]\tag{3}$$
So it turns out that your last block diagram looks exactly like eq (3). That diagram indeed look strange especially with a feedback loop and a gain of -1 (which is a stability concern). So it's worth digging a bit deeper and represent it as a standard difference equations without state variables.
We can rewrite eq (1) as $f[n-1] = y[n]-x[n]$ and pop that into eq (3). We get
$$ f[n] = -x[n] + 0.5y[n] - y[n] + x[n] = -0.5y[n] \tag{4}$$
We can put this back into equation (1) and get simply
$$ y[n] = x[n] - 0.5y[n-1] \tag{5} $$
So the whole thing is just a very simple filter and can be reduced to

The code SHOULD have read
f = 0;
for n in range(0, L-1):
    y[n] = x[n] + f;
    f = -0.5*y[n]


Thanks for the answer! That step to have "f[n] = -0.5 y[n]" is so tricky! I would never be able to figure that out just from the diagram!

You are welcome. Please note that the order of approach: I first transcribed the code into difference equations (DE) and than did algebra on the DE. That's how I came up with "f[n] = -0.5 y[n]"  I didn't see it from the code or the block diagram either.
